# Theme post editor does not have Visual & Html tabs and all buttons?

Tags: post-editor

My theme (which I made myself several years ago based on WP TwentyTen) is only showing a basic post editor (& I cannot remember whether this was so originally or not!).[image: see screenshot of post editor in my current WP Theme]

How do I get the post editor to revert/change to full Visual & Html mode with tabs and all buttons as per default WP TwentyEleven theme?-see screenshot below
[image: TwentyEleven post editor with tabs & all buttons]

I am most grateful for helpful replies-many thanks

EDIT 141212 -my own latest findings in trying to solve my original question....

By unchecking the box on admin page >users>admin I get a WordPress posteditor with Visual and Text tabs-see screen shots below:
[image]

Which gives this post editor:

[image]

What happened to the HTML tab?
Also the kitchen sink button doesn't work when I click on it?!

The WordPress editor seems a bit mysterious and less well documented and simple to use than I would like! (probably in line with the rest of WordPress now I think about it!). I hope this post may help anyone else who has questions over the WP post editor.

Answer (score 1):

Search for a filter on `'user_can_richedit'`. Remove that code from the theme. This is a perfect illustration for the argument that themes should do as little as possible. :)

The code will probably look like this:

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks toscho for your reply. I have checked my theme functions.php & this filter is not there.Any idea which file it maybe in otherwise?Is there another way to find it other than looking through every theme file individually?(I tried search function in website cpanel & nothing found).